# Maximum modulus theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness, maximum-principle

> (a) If $f(z)$ is analytic inside and on a simple closed curve $C$ enclosing $z=a$, prove that
>   $$ \left( f(a)\right)^n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)^n}{z-a} dz , \; \; n=1,2,3,...$$
>   (b) Use (a) to prove that $|f(a)|^n \le \frac{M^n}{2 \pi D}$ where $|f(z)| \le M$ on $C$ and $D$ is $\min \{ |z-a|\}$ on $C$.
>   (c) By taking $n$-th root on $(b)$ and taking $n \to \infty$ , prove Maximum Modulus theorem.

For far I thought $(a)$ follows from Cauchy-Integral where $f(a)^n$ would be the reside.

On $(b)$ shouldn't there be extra $\oint_C dz = L$ perimeter of the loop? And I don't have idea how it proves [Maximum Modulus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

And one quick question:- Is maximum modulus theorem valid for multiply connected region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in b., there should be the $L$ you mention. It however doesn't change the result, because following the hint we get 
$$|f(a)|\leqslant M,$$
hence $M$ is also the maximum for all the points which are enclosed by $C$.

Maximum modulus principle is true for domains (that is, connected open sets).

Comment: how does it prove (c), is it because $a$ is any arbitrary point inside the loop?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$